# What is the Equivalent CGPointZero in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want my UITextView to scroll to the top when the View appears.

```
UITextView*note;
[note setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

but could't find CGPointZero or CGPoint.Zero in Xamarin.iOS. So what is the equivalent of it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's `CGPoint.Empty` you can see it here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/CoreGraphics.CGPoint.Empty/

Answer (score 4):

It is CGPoint.Empty  and you can set

```
UITextView note = new UITextView(); 
note.SetContentOffset(CoreGraphics.CGPoint.Empty, true);
```